# How to write azure-pipeline.yaml script when integrating java webapp (.war) from azure devops repo into azure app service linux plan?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-web-app-service

I started with this first scirpt using task assistant but .war file wasn't finally deployed correctly, I need some help to organize this azure-pipeline.yaml file with the right commands to deploy app correctly.

```yaml
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
    displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'


- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: 'Free Trial(XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX)'
    appType: 'webAppLinux'
    WebAppName: 'usernamephp01'
    packageForLinux: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.war'
    RuntimeStack: 'TOMCAT|8.5-java11'
```

Comment: You said but .war file wasn't finally deployed correctly, but did not provide any information about it, is there any error or share the log here, so that we could to know the reason why it is not deployed correctly, Is yaml wrong or something else?

Comment: hello, assume that .war is a simple hello world java app hosted in azure repo.

Comment: hello, assume that .war file is a simple hello world java app hosted in azure repo. after decompression, files are : hello.jsp and folders META-INF WEB-INF.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT : this is my question, I need to know how to structure yaml file to integrate java hello world app into azure  appservice  from azure devops repo. Thnks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> How to write azure-pipeline.yaml script when integrating java webapp (.war) from azure devops repo into azure app service linux plan?

Since the application is java-based, we need to deploy the app into a proper directory structure. Try to use the [File Rename](https://github.com/kirkone/KK.VSTS.Extensions.FileOperations/blob/master/README.md) task to give it new name `ROOT.war`:

[image]

Then select the new name war file in the Package or folder selection of the Azure App Service Deploy task:

[image]

You could check [this document](https://devops.com/deploying-into-azure-app-service-using-azure-devops-ci-cd-pipeline/) for some more details.

Hope this helps.